# Raster2pgsql overview method

Tags: postgis, raster

What is the method used by Raster2pgsql to create overview? I couldn't find details in the docs. Nearest neighbor isn't a very good choice for the dataset I'm working on, but that seem to be the one used, just from visual inspection. I was hoping to be able to coerce something else. 
Does it use existing overviews? That would allow me to create them with whatever I like with gdaladdo then import those in PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

raster2pgsql uses VRTs for the overviews, which only supports NearestNeighbor. raster2pgsql does not support the consumption of existing overviews in files (mostly due to the scale factors used to generate those overviews). There are plans to remove the usage of VRTs in raster2pgsql due to the NearestNeighbor limitation and consume existing overviews but I don't know what that timeline is.